# Can I set an array length with a variable in Java?

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to establish a string array to hold the names of golfers in a scorecard application. I am asking for user input to get the number of players, and I would like to use that value to define the length of the array.  I have a variable to hold the value entered called NUM_PLAYERS, and I am having a problem getting it to define my array length.  String[ ] players = new String[NUM_PLAYERS];  When I get to my players entry loop I get the out of bounds exception as soon as I get past the first entry, because the array is only one element long.  Here is the ScoreCalc class and my run program as they stand so far:

[ScoreCalc class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efqdz.png)

[GameChicago program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5btL.png)

Comment: Post all code here directly as text.

Comment: Post the stack trace also

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to move the initialise of the array to the constructor like this

```
public class ScoreCalc {
  private String[] players;

  public ScoreCalc(int playersNum){
    this.players = new String[playersNum];
  }

  ...

}
```

and to create the class after you get the user's input, like this

```
input = ...
ScoreCalc game = new ScoreCalc(input)
```

you have some loop there of variables definition with the `NUM_PLAYERS`